# Where to store state of item of RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, model, android-viewbinding

I use Room database. Fragment observes items from the table and updates data in RecyclerView adapter.
I need to change states of items - such as Loading/Ready/Playing - to change items views (show progres etc.)
I try to add state var in item model(annotated @Ignore for Room) and change it, but view not changing.

Here's part of my code:

EntryItem model

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "EntryItems")
open class EntryItem {

    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("bind:setProgressView")
        @JvmStatic
        fun ProgressBar.setProgressView(entryItem: EntryItem) {
            when (entryItem.state) {
                is ItemState.Loading -> {
                    visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    progress = entryItem.state.loadedPercent
                }
                else -> visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }

        @BindingAdapter("bind:setLocalMark")
        @JvmStatic
        fun ImageView.setLocalMark(entryItem: EntryItem) {
            if (entryItem.local) visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    fun getFile(mediaProvider: MediaProvider, onEvent: (ItemState<Any?>) -> Unit) {

        mediaProvider.getFile(path, target, onLoading = { loadedPercent ->
            state = ItemState.Loading(loadedPercent)
            onEvent(state)
        },
        onLoaded = {
            state = ItemState.Loaded()
            local = true
            onEvent(state)
        })
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    open var path: String = ""
    
    @Ignore
    open var state: ItemState<Any?> = ItemState.Undefined

    @Ignore
    open var local: Boolean = false
}

sealed class ItemState<out T : Any?> {
    object Undefined : ItemState<Nothing>()
    data class Loading(val loadedPercent: Long = 0L) : ItemState<Long>()
    data class Loaded(val data: Any? = null) : ItemState<Any?>()
    data class Error(val errorData: Any?) : ItemState<Any?>()
}
```

Adapter

```kotlin
class RecyclerViewAdapter(var mediaProvider: MediaProvider) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var list: MutableList<EntryItem> = ArrayList()

    inner class ViewHolder(private var binding: EntryItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        
        fun bind(entryItem: EntryItem, position: Int) {
            binding.entryItem = list[position]
           
            binding.executePendingBindings()

            binding.entryItem?.getFile(mediaProvider) {
            
                binding.executePendingBindings()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

        val binding = EntryItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) =
        holder.bind(list[position], position)
}
```

Layout

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    bind:setProgressView="@{entryItem}"/>
```

`ProgressBar.setProgressView` `is ItemState.Loading` and `ImageView.setLocalMark` `if (entryItem.local)` not called.

Comment: Are you using a ViewModel anywhere?

Comment: @Tonnie yes, list of items placed in ViewModel: `val entryList: LiveData<List<EntryItem>> = repository.getItemsFromDB()`